# error installing panda on my windows 8

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I tried installing pandas on my windows 8 via the CMD but I get n error like 
"python setup-py egg_info" failed: with error code 1 in C:\users\username\APP Data\Local\Temp\pip-build-cbdsd3_x\pandas

Any clue on how I can resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide some more information on how you tried to install pandas via the CMD? For instance, did you use `pip`? What was the exact command line?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to visit : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

then download numpy+mkl wheel file. Then you can install pandas

Comment: Hello Mitir... I have download the numpy + mkl file... How do I install it?

Comment: I am assuming that file is located on the desktop
open command window: type cd desktop
Right click on the file and copy the file name
then in command window write: pip install (cop paste filename and don't forget to end file extension)

Comment: First uninstall pandas by pip uninstall pandas, then do what I told you and reinstall pandas

Comment: I followed a description for an online video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnpC_Ib_lbc) and I got this feedback 
its showing that numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported on this platform what to do?

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: if yours is python 3.5 then install numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win32.whl if your windows is 32 bit or
numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl if it is 64 bit. 

If it is python 3.6 then numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl or 
numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

Comment: Cenk..Thanks for taking our time for my question... I did this..                            I downloaded the file 'numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl' into my download file.. open my cmd and type this C:/Python34/Scripts/pip install numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl. The installation wasn';t successfully... I have managed to install numpy   but no scripy,matlibplot. Regards

Comment: I'm using python 34

Comment: maybe yours is 32 bit windows. did you try with numpy‑1.12.1+mkl‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl?

Comment: Cenk,,, I'm using a 64bit PC.. I uninstall the python 3.4  and install python 3,6,1 and  anaconda... panda, numpy are installed even beautifulsoup 4 but I'm trying to import panda into my shell and the response is no module is found.. any suggestion

Comment: it is strange so first you installed bumpy+mkl and pandas? Also try to install pandas from wheel file and see what happens

Comment: I did that and it didn;t work... I have to uninstall the python 3.4.. installed python 3.6 and anaconda but the only issue now is the path... the python app was installed into my c drive in a folder called python34 while the anaconda is in anaconda folder in my users folder... from the cmd, I can view the lib files (pandas etc) but from my IDLE.. if I try import it, it says no module found... importerror... how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) for Windows. It comes with a lot of libraries. You can refer [this](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) for a detailed list of packages installed and instructions on how to install external packages.

I was having trouble installing SciPy, Pandas and a few other libraries. Instead of solving issues for every library, I think installing Anaconda is a far better option. Plus, it comes with Spyder(IDE) and Jupyter notebook and a lot more other tools.

Comment: @Roy... Thank for your suggestions... My fear is I'm a novice in python.. I'm using a tutorial on youtube to learn web scraping and the instructor is using pandas. Can I replicate what I see on the video with the anaconda?!

Comment: I uninstall the python 3.4  and install python 3,6,1 and  anaconda... panda, numpy are installed even beautifulsoup 4 but I'm trying to import panda into my shell and the response is no module is found.. any suggestion

Comment: Here is what I noticed.. Python 3.6.1 file is in the one folder and the anaconda file is in another file.. This challenge can be a path issue... through my cmd.. I can access the modules but on my idle I can't. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi @AKP . Anaconda uses its own files. It installs Python inside its own folders. So, even if you have pyhton installed before, Anaconda will install it [separately](https://ibb.co/bJNPgF)
. Same goes for the libraries. Anaconda stores the libraries in its own installation [directory](https://ibb.co/f3vc1F). It has nothing to do with other python installations. That's why you can't access those libraries in CMD or IDLE. But you can use Spyder (an IDE that comes with Anaconda), or Anaconda's console( if you prefer command line).